# Python 3.6 - Can a variable value be used as part of a key value in a Dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am using Python 3.6

I can use the .format function to insert a variables value as part of a new variables value as per the below:

```
var_1 = "First_Var"

var_2 = "Second_Var_{}".format(var_1)

print (var_1, var_2)
```

This, when run, prints:

```
First_Var Second_Var_First_Var
```

I would like to be able to insert the value of var_1 and var_2 as values in a dict as per the below code:

```
var_1 = "First_Var"

var_2 = "Second_Var_{}".format(var_1)

dict_with_inserts = {'First_Var': '{}_inserted', 'Second_Var': '{}_inserted'}.format(var_1, var_2)

print (dict_with_inserts)
```

When I run the above I get the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'
```

So it seems I cant use the .format function on dicts. Is there an alternative way to do this or is it not possible to insert the value of a variable within a Python dict?

Any examples or help will be much appreciated.

Comment: In python 3.6, you can also use [literal strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (also called f-strings): `mydict = {'first_var': f'{var_1}_inserted'}`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, if you submit this as an answer I would accept it as correct - the other answers are good and do work but your way is the more modern and also makes for shorter code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3.6, you can also use [literal strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (also called f-strings):

```
var_1 = 'teststring'

mydict = {'first_var': f'{var_1}_inserted'}

print(mydict)
>> {'first_var': 'teststring_inserted'}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, your answer seems to be the most relevant for Python 3.6 and also allows for the shortest code - the other answers where good and do what is needed but I think yours deserves to be accepted as correct in the strictest sense...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var_1 = "First_Var"

var_2 = "Second_Var_{}".format(var_1)

dict_with_inserts = {'First_Var': '{}_inserted'.format(var_1), 
'Second_Var': '{}_inserted'.format(var_2)}

print (dict_with_inserts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var_1 = "First_Var"
var_2 = "Second_Var_{}".format(var_1)

dict_with_inserts = {'First_Var': '{}_inserted'.format(var_1), 'Second_Var': '{}_inserted'.format(var_2)}

print (dict_with_inserts)
```

Answer (score 1):

the .[format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) function works on strings alone

However this will achieve the same result as what you are trying to do:

```
var_1 = "First_Var"

var_2 = "Second_Var_{}".format(var_1)

dict_with_inserts = {'First_Var': '{}_inserted'.format(var_1), 'Second_Var': '{}_inserted'.format(var_2)}

print (dict_with_inserts)
```